# Is deriving from exception classes the only way to make an object 'throwable' in C#?

Tags: .net, exception, object

Can I some how make my non-exception objects become 'throwable' so that any local variables declared in a `try` block like `obj` in the try block below

```
try
{ 
   SomeObject obj = new SomeObject(); 
}catch {}
```

can cross the scope boundary into the catch{} clause?? I want to use the `obj` instance in the catch{} clause even if its state is compromised. Is this possible somehow ?

Maybe possible(?) as the C# compiler maybe doing similar (for optimization I'd assume?) and allows the catch clause to receive any System.Object but I can't use that in VS, for this method:

```
public void Foo()
{

    try
    {
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }

    try
    {
    }
    catch
    {
    }

}
```

generates this IL:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void  Foo() cil managed
{
  // Code size       22 (0x16)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Exception ex)
  IL_0000:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_0001:  nop
    IL_0002:  nop
    IL_0003:  leave.s    IL_000a
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
  {
    IL_0005:  stloc.0
    IL_0006:  nop
    IL_0007:  nop
    IL_0008:  leave.s    IL_000a
  }  // end handler
  IL_000a:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_000b:  nop
    IL_000c:  nop
    IL_000d:  leave.s    IL_0014
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Object     /* <-- I want to do like this*/
  {
    IL_000f:  pop
    IL_0010:  nop
    IL_0011:  nop
    IL_0012:  leave.s    IL_0014
  }  // end handler
  IL_0014:  nop
  IL_0015:  ret
} // end of method Class::Foo
```

Is there a way (managed/unmanged) to 'cheat' like that and define a 'throwable' behavior for the `SomeObject` type so that I can reserve my right to inherit from meaningful classes and not have to inherit from exception classes just make an object 'throwable' ?

How about if I do like this (which is pretty much have I do it currently):

```
SomeObject obj = null; 
try
{ 
   obj = new SomeObject(); 
}catch {}
```

is performance slower if obj is defineed inside or outside the `try` clause as t looks they are both generating identical local to the method (not the try scope) storage variable - you get `.locals init ([0] class ClassLibrary.Class obj` in the IL either way so maybe its not slower if the variable is never initted ? In other words if I have `SomeObject obj = null;` defined *anywhere* inside a method code but I never initialize it to an actual instance of `SomeObject`, does it matter (performance wise) if my varuable definition is inside the try/catch scope or global to the entire function scope(not inside try/catch) ?

Comment: Out of curiosity what were you planning on doing in the catch?

Comment: s So are you encountering a specific exception or is this a general "something bad might happen here and I want to know what's going on"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(EDIT: Sorry, I've just seen that you suggested this right at the end of your post. Basically it's the right thing to do!)

No, you can't throw anything that doesn't derive from Exception. But it would be the wrong thing to do anyway - just declare the variable earlier:

```
SomeObject obj = null;
try
{ 
    obj = new SomeObject(); 
    // Other stuff
}
catch (IOException e) // Or whatever
{
    // Now you can refer to obj
}
```

Just be aware that `obj` may be null, if an exception was thrown before the variable was assigned its new value (for example if the `SomeObject` constructor threw an exception).

No, you won't suffer any performance problems due to this - at least, if there *are* any effects, they'll be insignificant. The code may end up *actually* performing an extra assignment, but the chances of that being relevant are practically non-existent.

Comment: Constructors should never throw exceptions, otherwise there is evil code in it, which needs to be removed.

Comment: @ivo s: Well, look at your original code (one assignment) and the final code (two - one of null, the other not). It's possible that the JIT can optimize that out, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Danny: I disagree completely. It's *entirely reasonable* for constructors to throw exceptions in C#, and many standard library classes do. What do you *want* `new List<int>(-10)` to do? It's a bad thing if a constructor throws an exception having acquired a resource, and in that case it should definitely dispose of it appropriately... but that's a special case.

Comment: @Danny Chen: A constructor not being able to construct a new instance of the desired object is an exceptional situation. How else do you propose that failure-to-construct be signaled?

Comment: @ivo: Yes, scope itself only exists at compile-time. I *would* expect to see the extra assignment though, at least in a debug build. But it's not the kind of thing I get hung up on :)

Comment: @ivo: It's just inappropriate, normally. Either an object is logically an exception or it isn't - if you want to pass up state within the exception, you should wrap that state in the exception itself, as The River suggested.

Comment: @ivo: It's not clear what you mean by "if I throw my object" - then an exception *has* occurred... and exceptions *are* objects. It's really not clear what you're envisaging.

Answer (score 1):

A previous answer has already recommended moving the declaration of `SomeObject obj` to before the *try* block. If you need to access *obj* higher in the call stack, you can create a subclass of *Exception* that contains a property of type *SomeObject*, which you can use to pass *obj* around:

```
class SomeObjectException : Exception
{
  // Constructors here
  public SomeObject Object { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
throw new SomeObjectException { Object = obj };
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `Object` as a member name, even if it can be compiled.

Comment: Just noting that you still need to define `obj` outside of the `try{}` scope to use this method

Comment: Good insight, however, you'll probably want to encapsulate the exception class more tightly by getting rid of the `set` and moving initialization to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to worry about that kind of performance issues? The bottle neck will not be your try/catch or variable declaration/initializations.

```
SomeObject obj = null; 
try
{ 
   obj = new SomeObject(); 
}
catch (SpecificException err)
{
   //use obj here.
}
```

Is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any other way to bahave like Exception by inhrit from Exception.
I don't understand why do you need to change it.
Yes, I guess if you put the try, the operations will lazy more.

Answer (score 0):

First, no, there is no way to define a variable inside a block and access it outside of the block. It doesn't matter if it is a try block, a catch block or something else. Blocks define the scope of a variable, and variables defined inside the block are scoped to that level. And when something goes out of scope, it becomes eligible for garbage collection (assuming ref counts are 0, etc, etc).

If you need to access the variable outside of the block, what you did at the end is absolutely correct. If you are using try/catch, you have way more performance problems to worry about than the variable declaration happening outside (since a catch involves walking the frames to find a handler, etc, etc).

What you /could/ do is throw your own custom exception with the object in the data. I wouldn't recommend doing that, since it isn't clear to me what you want to do. If you just want to clean it up, then just declare it outside. Or, if you aren't going to do anything with the exception, for heavens sake use the `using` declaration. Yes, your object needs to implement `IDisposable`, but if you have clean up code to do there, technically you may as well be.

One last thing. You said:

> I want to use the obj instance in the catch{} clause even if its state is compromised.

Note there are instances when state can be compromised and there isn't a darn thing you can do about it. `StackOverflow`, `ExecutionEngineException` and `OutOfMemoryException` all come to mind. Also, when you are using multithreaded code, all bets are off if you aren't locking properly.

For a quick intro into things like memory management, exception handling, etc, you can take a look at [this presentation](http://blog.coryfoy.com/2010/02/debugging-net-applications-with-windbg-and-sos/) I did on Debugging .NET with WinDBG and SOS.